# Using checkboxes to pass info to next form

Tags: php, post, checkbox

I run a query

```
$querymail=mysql_query
("select sp.player_num as Pnum,concat(sp.first_name,' ',sp.last_name)as PName,
st.name as Team, sp.email_address as Email,spt_league_id as League, ss.Season_name
as Season from stats_player sp inner join stats_player_team stp,
stats_team st, stats_season ss 
where stp.player_num = sp.player_num and sp.email_address<>''
and st.team_num=stp.team_id and ss.season_index=stp.season_id and
ss.season_index=$this_season  order by st.name;");
```

and then output to a forum/table that has check boxes.

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($querymail))
{

echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkemail'
value=".$row'Pnum']."checked></td><td>".$row['PName']."</td><td>".$row['Email'].
"</td><td>".$row['Team'].' ' .$row['League'].' '.$row['Season']."</td></tr>";


}
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
}
```

It then send that info to a nother page to display info and then send to email addresses selected.

My query is good and the table displays correctly.
I am unsure if I am actually gathering the correct information though via the check boxes. and that is where I need some help.

I want to collect sp.player_num of each checked item and pass to the next page.
I will then do a lookup of the player num and email and set a email routine for that. but I can't seem to get anything to pass to next page.

I do a print_r($_POST) in emailall.ph but it returns empty.

Will I need to use Session_Start in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a opening `form` tag.

```
echo "<form method='post' action='emailall.php'>";
```

You need to make the checkbox an array, note the `[]` which was added to the name field.

```
echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkemail[]'
value='".$row['Pnum']."' checked></td><td>".$row['PName']."</td><td>".$row['Email'].
"</td><td>".$row['Team'].' ' .$row['League'].' '.$row['Season']."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: I actually do have `echo "<form name='email' method='post' Action='emailall.php'>";` It just got trimmed off when I was copying it over to here. I added `[]` to the name field and that made it work!!!!! Thank you very much.